# After insert exception with Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool

Tags: trigger, validation, exception, insert, dlrs

I have a validation on account that throws an error if the below is true

```
Locked__c = True && 
NOT(ISCHANGED( One_Time_Support_Counter__c )) && 
NOT(ISCHANGED( Last_One_Time_Support_date__c ))
```

When I create a case sometimes I get the following error and sometimes not.

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger dlrs_CaseTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: dlrs_CaseTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id _____ ; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You cannot modify this account!: []: Class.dlrs.RollupService.Updater.updateRecords: line 692, column 1

Sometimes I can save without checking the "boxLast_One_Time_Support_date__c", and sometimes even if both fields are changed I still get this error.

Please advice
Thank you

Comment: The error is on your trigger. You need to show us your code for dlrs_CaseTrigger and probably some apex class as well. But I am pretty sure we need to trigger code.

Comment: I'd assume that when your case is updated, the DLRS tool is trying to update the Account, but it can't because of that validation rule.  The DLRS obviously knows nothing about your validation rule, so you either need to remove the validation rule, or update it so this scenario doesn't happen.

Comment: @Lance Shi I cant see the code, its a managed unlisted package from appExchange.

Comment: @Nick Cook Correct, it knows nothing about my code, however the change I make does not meet the scenario. The account record has a lock checkbox that is checked, but I do update both the fields that need to be changed to prevent the validation from triggering.

Comment: @user8310 So turning the validation rule off doesn't help?  What do you mean, you update both the fields?  Remember that the execution context you're talking about here is based on the Case record, not the Account.  As such, it's unlikely those two fields would be updated within the same execution context.

Comment: This validation in on the account. When creating a Case it updates rollups on the account. However if the account is locked i want to prevent changes unless its the 2 rollup fileds coming from case. (On Account) Locked__c = True && 
NOT(ISCHANGED( One_Time_Support_Counter__c )) && 
NOT(ISCHANGED( Last_One_Time_Support_date__c ))

Comment: @user8310 aah, so those two fields are the fields that are updated by the DLRS tool?

Comment: Yes, it is updated by the tool.

Comment: I have since removed the validation rule and replaced it by an after update trigger on account. When a case is created and it updates those two fields it it will fire the account trigger, however I still get an error. I thought perhaps its updating two fields but somehow not in the same transaction, so I removed one of the fields and the rule says that if its locked only update field x otherwise add.error. I'm still getting an error and not sure where the problem is.